# os.system('sudo shutdown now -P') doesn't work with cloud-init

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I want to launch an Amazon EC2 instance programmatically, use cloud-init to execute a Python script, then have this same script terminate the instance. Everything works fine, except for the self-termination part. I've tried this:

```
os.system('sudo shutdown now -P')
```

And this:

```
os.system('sudo -n shutdown now -P')
```

And also this:

```
os.popen('sudo -S shutdown now -P')
```

No good. In all cases the `/var/log/cloud-init.log` file shows `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`.

Apparently commenting out the `Default requiretty` line on `/etc/sudoers` does the trick, but I want to do things programmatically, so I guess that's not an option here (and it probably would require root privileges as well, which takes us back to square one).

I suppose I could use a multi-part cloud-init script - say, follow the Python script with a bash script that does the self-termination. But surely there must be a way to solve this from within Python?

(Amazon Linux. Python 2.7.5. Boto 2.23)

Comment: I'm confused why don't you want to comment out the appropriate line "/etc/sudoers" and do the `sudo shutdown` command "programmatically"?

Comment: Pardon my nOOb question, but is there a way to comment out the `Default requiretty` line programmatically then? And wouldn't that itself require root privileges?

Comment: Sorry, I meant you can do the `sudo shutdown` command programmatically after you login and modify the system file. Why do you need to modify the file from the same script?

Comment: Because I don't actually login, I'm passing the script via cloud-init.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot shutdown a Linux system without appropriate privileges (required by [reboot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html) syscall).

And you need root privileges to edit `/etc/sudoers` to enable `sudo` without password.

If what you try was possible, there would be no protection on Linux, which is (like all Unixes) a [multi-user](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-user) operating system.

Comment: Suppose I change `/etc/sudoers` manually then re-bundle the AMI. Would that change propagate to new instances?

Comment: Ok, I'll try that and report back here.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an AWS-only solution, but...

I launched an EC2 instance, SSH'd into it, manually commented out the `Default requiretty` on `/etc/sudoers`, saved the change, created an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) based on that instance, then used that AMI to launch all other instances. The change on `/etc/sudoers` propagates to any instance based on that AMI, so `os.system('sudo shutdown now -P')` will work fine.